# is possible use external javascript libraries with Pit or Websharper?

Tags: f#, websharper

I'm interesting in found an alternative to javascript (I don't like coffeescript) and I like the functional paradigm.

I've seen 2 f# projects than compile code to javascript, pit and websharper, pit only support jquery and it's very recent, websharper support several libs but obviously isn't enough for complex apps..is possible extend the supported libs in a simple way?...reading the websharper documentation I saw than websharper support something named stubs util for do bindings between f# and js and  "Interface Generator"  than actually I can't understand reading only the documentation...has pit something similar to it?...

thanks

Comment: I tend to agree with @toyvo--why do you think WebSharper isn't capable of dealing with "complex apps"?  Any app that does more than display "Hello World" can potentially become very complex in short order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebSharper has bindings to Ext JS, Kendo UI, Raphael, Sencha Touch, YUI, Google Vis, WebGL, and others, see http://websharper.com/downloads

Get it and give it a try. Yes, you can easily bind other JavaScript frameworks.

Having developed several large projects with WebSharper, I cannot help but wonder about your claim that "websharper .. isn't enough for complex apps". How do you arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: would be nice see an binding example..it's hard found examples or tutos abot websharper, and this has many "obscure edges"